# Derivative of displacement in deriving expression for intensity of sound waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, differentiation

I am currently working on deriving the expression for intensity of a sound wave: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/17-3-sound-intensity

The previously mentioned book states: "The velocity of the medium is the time rate of change in the displacement: $$v(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}s(x,t)=s_{max}\omega\sin(kx-\omega t+\phi)$$

I am confused why we differentiate with respect to $y$ rather than $t$. Given the final result, $x$ was treated as a constant and the result makes sense if we differentiate with respect to $t$ (although missing a negative sign?). What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a typo and the negative sign disappears because it is a cosine function, $s(x,t)=s_{\rm max}\cos(kx∓ωt+ϕ)$, which is being differentiated.

$y$ is the displacement of the centre of mass of a parcel of the medium from its equilibrium position at a **fixed** position $x$ from the origin.
So this displacement relates to the movement of the medium not the movement of the wave profile (a "photograph" of the wave at one instant of time).

Answer (score 2):

If we assume a sinusoidal wave with wavelength $\frac {2 \pi}{k}$ and period $\frac {2 \pi} {\omega}$ then $s(x,t) = s_{max} \cos(kx - \omega t + \phi)$ and we have

$\displaystyle \frac {\partial s}{\partial t} = s_{max} \omega \sin(kx - \omega t + \phi)$

So it seems likely that $y$ is a typo for $t$, especially if $y$ is not defined elsewhere in the text.

(Having read the text, the sentence before the equation reads "The velocity of the medium is the time rate of change in the displacement", which makes it almost certain that $y$ is indeed intended to be $t$).